# How to find elements when child element exists or not with JQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, css, selector

Here is a sample html code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="zone">
       <img class="thumb" alt="GG">
   </div>
   <div class="zone">
       <span>&nbsp;</span>
   </div>
   <div class="zone">
       <img class="thumb" alt="HH">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to match all `div` with the `zone` class that have `img` with `alt=GG` or no `img` at all.

The following code doesn't work:

```
$('div.zone img[alt="GG"], :not(div.zone:has(img))')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. It confirm works, the wanted zone are bordered RED. (Edited: Thanks PSL)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.zone:has(img[alt='GG']),div.zone:not(:has(img))").css("border","1px solid red");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't give a div this gives image and a div. instead of 2 divs that meets the criteria.

Comment: Now you edited how is it different from my answer? I posted ages back.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully TS revisit the answer. Yeah. Apparently, the modified answer is the same. I missed the div.zone on the second part as well.

Comment: Exactly that is what i meant. There is already a similar answer posted times back. Also your edit history shows your old answer which was apparently wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var $specialDivs= $('div.zone:has("img[alt="GG"]"), div.zone:not(:has(img))');
                              ^    ^                          ^        ^
                              |    |                          |        |
                       div.zone has image with alt      div.zone not having any image
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSBud/)**

issue with your selector is that `'div.zone img[alt="GG"]` a  space between div and image will look for the div.zone whose children having the image with alt attribute. whereas the image is direct descendant of `div.zone`, hence your selector will not get you anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jquery for do this. Just with CSS selectors you can do it: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KGFz7/1)

Here is the CSS selector:

```
.container > div.zone img,
.container > div.zone img[alt="GG"] {
    background: red;
}
```

Cheers,
Leo!

Comment: I'm sorry , your answer is incorrect since it doesn't match the second div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method

```
$('div.zone').filter(function() {
   return !$(this).find('img').length || $(this).find('img[alt="GG"]').length
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QXCBj/)**

Comment: I'd prefer a solution with selector only.